# How to define "complex" structures in C

Tags: c, struct

Suppose I have two simple structures:

```
  struct Point{

        double x;
        double y;

    };

    struct Err{

        double xx;
        double xy;
        double yy;

    };
```

I have two options to define complex structures:

**OPTION 1 - DIRECT**

```
struct Measure {

    Point P;
    Err E;

};

struct State {

    Measure Pos;
    Measure Vel;
    Measure Acc;

};
```

**OPTION 2 - POINTERS**

```
struct PMeasure {

    Point *P;
    Err *E;

};

struct PState {

    Measure *Pos;
    Measure *Vel;
    Measure *Acc;

};
```

What are the pros and cons for these two options ?

Comment: Option 2 can cause memory issues if your Measure * are created on the heap and you forget to free them before deleting your struct, as they will not be freed automatically.

Comment: There is no such thing as a C/C++ and you don't have derived structures in your example.

Comment: Use smart pointer to avoid memory leak. But why you want this "nested" structure? It's actually "has a"  relationship rather than "is a".

Comment: @Ron I didn't mean "derived" in the c++ sense rather I meant derived in the sense of  defining "complex" structures with simpler ones

Comment: Do you want a c++ answer or a c answer?

Comment: @ThomasSablik As I answered to Ron I meant in the c sense and **not** in the c++ inheritance sense

Comment: "more correct way" depends on your needs. From the current setup I see no reason why you would use pointers, but cannot see how you use them elsewhere.

Comment: @George Have revised my tags to C

Comment: An alternative is to use arrays of the specified size (if number of members is known at compile time) or a standard container (like `std::vector<>`) if the size is not known until run time.   These and other options can achieve exactly the same effect.   Which is more (or less) correct depends on requirements.

Comment: Why not go the whole hog with the pointers and define `struct Point { double *x; double *y; };` `struct Err { double *xx; double *xy; double *yy; };`? I'm only joking there, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: @IanAbbott Well I could, but I think there is a difference between primitve types and other types

Comment: @BennyK Unless your non-primitive types are long or variable length arrays, I'd avoid the pointers.

Comment: Which is better: a truck or a bike? Answer: it depends on what you want to use them for.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite A truck, because you can run over a bike with it but you can't do the opposite

Comment: @BennyK: Ever tried to drive a truck through a small way between houses? Siad that: you might want to look up the concepts of sarcasm and retorical questions. It's often better to carefully think about something which sounds completely unrelated on the first impression. One required skill for programming is to think and research for oneself.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Hmmmm.... sarcasm... you don't say....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1

- Easy to copy
- Easy to initialize
- Hard to move (must copy the data to the new struct)
- No risk of memory leaks

Option 2

- Hard to copy since you need to not only memcpy the struct but all its pointer members
- Hard to initialize (need to set the pointers of all the members to something sensible)
- Easy to move (just move the pointers no need to copy the data)
- Risk of memory leak if one forgets to free pointers

Therefore for simple stuff I would go for option 1. But for more complex stuff, use option 2 but wrap all initialization,cloning and destruction into specific functions.

Answer (score 3):

There are two situations where you want to use pointers and `malloc`, `realloc`, `free` in C:

- Your object is very large. At least a hundred bytes.
- You don't know how many objects you're going to have, so you need an expanding array. Or fancier lists, maps, hashes or trees.

Your objects here don't look like they need pointers. You might end up needing a pointer to the start of a `State` array.

Comment: Except if variable is global/static.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you want allocate the actual memory. Option 1 allocates the memory together with the struct. Option 2 assumes memory is allocated elsewhere.

Meaning that option 1 is probably most useful in the general case. If you are a beginner you can stop reading here and pick option 1.

Option 2 could have its specialized uses, if you for example wish to build up things like look-up tables, or if you for some reason *must* use heap allocation of all objects (if they are too large to fit on the stack, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you create a pointer you have to allocate space and save that spaces's address into your pointer. What are you going to write is important here. You can either allocate statically, or allocate dynamically. Whenever you allocate a space, you have to release whenver you don't need them anymore. It actually depends on your design which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot understand why the 2nd option could cause *memory issues*, then stick to option 1. Pointers are great and are the way to use dynamic memory allocation in C language, or to directly access other variables. But:

1. you cannot use a pointer unless it points to a valid object or to some allocated memory
2. every allocated piece of memory must be freed to avoid memory leaks

If you do not strictly observe above rules, then your program will have memory issues...